# xarray load() running slowly on open_mfdataset() data

Tags: dask, python-xarray

It is taking 21 seconds to run `xarray.DataArray.values` for a dataset that I have opened with `open_mfdataset()`.

Getting the values from a larger array that I opened with `open_dataset()` is over 1000 times quicker. EDIT: looping over the multiple files using a for loop is also much quicker than using `open_mfdataset()`. See edit at the bottom.

Could you help me to understand why this happens, or what to look for, and if there is a faster way for me to open 40 netCDFs, do some selecting, and export the selected data to numpy?

My code is along these lines:

```py
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(myfiles_list, concat_dim='new_dim')
ds = ds.sel(time=selected_date)
ds = ds.sel(latitude=slice([ymin, ymax]), longitude=slice([xmin, xmax]))
vals = ds['temperature'].values        # this line takes 18.9 secs

# total time: 21 secs
# vals.shape = (40, 1, 26, 17)
```

vs

```py
onefile = xr.open_dataset('/path/to/data/single_file.nc')
vals = onefile['temperature'].values   # this line takes 0.005 secs

# total time: 0.018 secs
# vals.shape = (93, 40, 26, 17)
```

Thanks.

**EDIT - Extra Info:**

I should clarify that it seems to be the loading that is slow. When `values` is called an array that was previously lazy [gets loaded](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html#using-dask-with-xarray). If I insert an explicit `load()` command then the loading is slow but the values command is then quick:

```py
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(myfiles_list, concat_dim='new_dim')
ds = ds.sel(time=selected_date)
ds = ds.sel(latitude=slice([ymin, ymax]), longitude=slice([xmin, xmax]))
ds = ds.load()                         # this line takes 19 secs
vals = ds['temperature'].values        # this line takes <10 ms

# total time: 21 secs
# vals.shape = (40, 1, 26, 17)
```

If, instead of using `open_mfdataset()`, I do a for loop over my list of files, extract a numpy array from each one, and do the concatenation in numpy then it only takes 1 second. In this MWE this solves my whole problem, but in my complete code I do need to use `open_mfdataset()`:

```py
list_of_arrays = []
for file in myfiles_list:
    ds = xr.open_dataset(file)
    ds = ds.sel(time=selected_date)
    ds = ds.sel(latitude=slice([ymin, ymax]), longitude=slice([xmin, xmax]))
    list_of_arrays.append(ds['temperature'].values)

vals = np.concatenate(list_of_arrays, axis=0)

# total time: 1.0 secs
# vals.shape = (40, 26, 17)
```

Comment: So your `single_file` contains all the files parsed from `myfiles_list`?

Comment: my ```single_file``` contains lots of extracts from the ```myfiles_list``` files. It is smaller than the total file size of the ```myfiles_list``` files.

Answer (score 0):

`xarray.open_mfdataset` will make a python list of `xarray.Datasets` and will concatenate them after all files parsed to the list.
So multiple times data has to be opened and stored into a list. If you profile the code, you will recognize that the file parsing takes the most time but it does not correlate to the size of the file. So a 2 times bigger file will not take 2 times more time to parse. In the end concatenation itselfs takes time.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is loading the values from the files that is taking most of time, but also, using ```xarray.open_mfdataset``` is much slower than looping over the files individually then concatenating in numpy.  I added some more info to my question.

Comment: Good point. Maybe some of the xarray contributor will read this thread and has a better explanation.